# cmd loop and output subfolder location

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, subdirectory

Can anyone tell me how to set up a .bat file that would do the following in windows:

let's say I have: c:\somefolder\ from which I run dostuff.bat which then prints the full addresses of the subfolders in  c:\somefolder\

e.g.:

```
c:\somefolder\sub1\subsub1\
c:\somefolder\sub1\subsub2\
c:\somefolder\sub1\subsub3\
c:\somefolder\sub2\subsub1\
...
...
```

It only needs to go two levels down, if that helps.

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `FOR /D` command

```
for /D %%A in ("C:\temp\*") do (
    echo %%A
    for /D %%2 in ("%%~A\*") do echo --- %%~2
)
```

Comment: Um... does such thing as `%%2` exist in batch scripting? Did you mean `%%B` by any chance?

Comment: @Andriy M: %%2 or %%B is handled equal, nearly every character can be used for this, even a percent sign `for %%%% in (test) do echo %%~%%`

Comment: Wow, that's nice. I'll try to remember that when I've run out of the 52 letter vars. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DOS port of the `find` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d
```

[Download GNU utilities to get find.exe here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)

Comment: +1, it solves it as one liner, but it seems to be a little bit of overkill to use/download the gnu utils only for this

Answer (score 1):

I think, `FOR` with the options `/D` and `/R path` should give you the desired output:

```
FOR /R "C:\temp" /D %%A IN (*) ECHO %%A
```

If you specifically wish the output to contain `\` at the end, put it explicitly after `%%A`:

```
... ECHO %%A\
```